# build absolute value equations know solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

We have absolute value equations with unknown coefficients:
$$|x + a| = b$$
and we know the solutions:
$$x = 11 \text{ and } x = 5$$

We need to find $a$ and $b$. From
$$11 + a = b \\
5 + a = -b$$
we get $a = -8$ and $b = 3$.

But we can try another way:
$$11 + a = -b \\
5 + a = b$$
and get $a =8$ and $b = -3$, which is not correct, apparently we need take absolute value from $b$.

How can I formulate this rule and explain it to another person?

Comment: Shouldn't the first solution be $a = -8$?

Comment: @shardulc, correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to solve $|x + a| = b$ where we know that the solutions for $x$ are 11 and 5. Since it's an absolute value, $b$ must be positive and therefore $b > -b$. We might try to solve
$$11 + a = -b \qquad 5 + a = b$$
But $11 + a > 5 + a$ and $-b$ cannot be greater than $b$. So we are left with
$$11 + a = b \qquad 5 + a = -b$$
which can be solved using simultaneous equations to get $a = -8$ and $b = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Plug $x=11$ into the original equation and square both sides. Do the same with $x=5$. We obtain
$$(11+a)^2=b^2=(5+a)^2.\tag1$$
Expanding (1) and solving for $a$ we get
$$121+22a+a^2=25+10a+a^2\ \Longleftrightarrow\ a=-8$$
Plugging this value of $a$ back into the original equation, this gives
$$b=\vert 11+a\vert=\vert 5+a\vert=3.$$